# how to override STL container function

Tags: c++, stl

It's possible, that override some function stl container with the same paremeters?
I want override exactly `push_back` with some `if` inside function.
I try but, always have error/information about that function is in vector.

Comment: No, you can't change `vector`.  Sounds like an XY problem though.  What is it that you actually need to accomplish?

Comment: Can't you put the checks you need to do *outside* the function, so you only call `push_back` with the right conditions matched?

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error with your code please post a [mcve] that generates that error.

Comment: I want check size element which is `push_back` to container and add when he perform some condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding means that you are going to inherit from *STL* container. Don't do that! *STL* containers are not designed for inheriting from them.

---

As an option, you might encapsulate *std::vector* into some wrapper class and perform additional functionality before pushing, something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    void push(U&& e)
    {
         // some additional processing
         data.push_back(std::forward<U>(e));
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance for STL containers is bad approach. The vector is not supposed to have derived classes. There are no virtual method in the vector and virtual destructor ( the last one could make a lot of problems ).
You can create your own class and use vector as member.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that. Most classes in the `std` library are not meant to be inherited from. However, instead of changing it "from the inside" just do it "from the outside", for example:

```
template<typename T> myPush(std::vector<T>& v,T element) {
    if (someCondition()) { v.push(element); }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
struct MyCustomVector {
     void my_push( T element);
     /* pulic or private: */          // depends on what you want/need
     std::vector<T> vect;
};
```